# Populate kubernetes Configmap from hashicorp vault

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

i want to populate configmaps from data inside vault in kubernetes. I just complete setup of vault and auth method as `kubernetes(Service account)` and `userpass`.

Can someone suggest easy way to integrate variables for application ? what to add in yaml file ? if i can populate configmap then i can easily use it to yaml.

how to changes will be affected if variable change on vault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using [Vault CRD](https://vault.koudingspawn.de), when you create a custom resource of type vault, it will create a secrets using a data from the vault

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vault CRD as Xavier Adaickalam mentioned.

Regarding the subject of variable changes, you have 2 ways of exposing variables inside Pods, [using volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) and [using environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables). Volumes are updated automatically when the secrets are modified. Unfortunately, environment variables do not receive updates even if you modify your secrets. You have to restart your container if the values are modified.

Comment: hi there thanks for writing answer very particular answer i was wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: actually just an update, now you can use external secrets to keep them updated:
https://external-secrets.io/v0.8.1/